R formula syntax for quadratic function
I have a quadratic model that I am trying to fit with mgcv::gam, and I need some help in coding it as an r formula:

My attempt so far:
model <- mgcv::gam(W ~ 1 + z + I(0.5*z^2))

Do you think this is the correct syntax for the formula? That is, does the formula match the equation I am trying to use? I am not exactly sure whether the 0.5 is placed correctly.

It's not clear why you're using mgcv::gam() if you're not going to include any smooth terms (s()) in your formula ... @Eonema is right that the answer to this question is independent of whether you're using lm(), glm(), or gam() (see ?formula)

I am using mgcv::gam() because I compare the model to other models that include smooth terms. However, this question is about the (1/2) in the formula and whether this term is incorporated correctly in the model.

The 1 in the formula will be interpreted as an unknown intercept to be estimated, not as a constant of 1. I think W ~ -1 + offset(rep(1, length(z))) + z + I(0.5*z^2) will do what you want. The -1 specifies that there is no intercept and offset(rep(1, length(z))) serves as the 1 in your equation. This works for stats::glm, so it should also work for mcgv::gam according to the help page, but I'm not familiar with mcgv so there might be quirks I'm not aware of.
